# chart.js - problem with label on the right hand

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I use chart.js and I would like to display labels at the right of each bar but I got a problem with the first label.

I use the plugin [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/#table-of-contents) it work but the first label is hidden.

Do you know how to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/rq78pg4j/1/

```
var ctx4 = $('#chart_choice');
        var chart_market = new Chart(ctx4, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Legend 1', 'Legend 2'],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [12, 10],
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(243,212,205,1)',
                        'rgba(243,212,205,1)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(223,142,123,1)',
                        'rgba(223,142,123,1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        align: 'end',
                        anchor: 'end',
                        color: '#0B4892',
                        font: function(context) {
                            var w = context.chart.width;
                            return {
                                size: w < 512 ? 12 : 14,
                                weight: 'bold',
                            };
                        },
                        formatter: function(value, context) {
                            return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't even show the labels

Comment: It shows when you hover the mouse over one of the boxes.

Comment: Hello @Jandon I've found this: https://dev.to/giselamd/creating-a-custom-chart-js-legend-style-50i5 There might be some useful piece of code in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Chart.js` is not aware of what `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` is doing. Therefore, it doesn't reserve enough space at the right of the chart, allowing the labels of the largest bars to appear on the `canvas`.

This can be fixed by defining extra padding at the right of the chart as follows.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      right: 100
    }
  },
  ...
```

> For further details, please consult the page [Layout Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html) from the `Chart.js` documentation.